# user input array program keeps returning 255

Tags: c++, arrays, crash

I might have done something wrong.  All I know is that the program keeps crashing when it should be getting to display the array.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int findSmallestRemainingElement(int input_values[], int size, int index);

void swap(int input_values[], int first_index, int second_index);

void insertionSort(int input_values[], int size);

void displayArray(int input_values[], int size);

int* userInput(int input_values[], int size);

int main()
{
    int input_values[50];
    userInput(input_values, 50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        cout << input_values[i];
    }
    insertionSort(input_values, 50);
    displayArray(input_values, 50);
    cout << "\n";
}

void insertionSort(int input_values[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int index = findSmallestRemainingElement(input_values, size, i);
        swap(input_values, i, index);
    }
}

int findSmallestRemainingElement(int input_values[], int size, int index)
{
    int index_of_smallest_value = index;
    for (int i = index + 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (input_values[i] < input_values[index_of_smallest_value])
        {
            index_of_smallest_value = i;
        }
    }
    return index_of_smallest_value;
}

void swap(int input_values[], int first_index, int second_index)
{
    int temp = input_values[first_index];
    input_values[first_index] = input_values[second_index];
    input_values[second_index] = temp;
}

void displayArray(int input_values[], int size)
{
    cout << input_values[0] << endl;

    cout << input_values[24] << endl;

    cout << input_values[49] << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            cout << "\n";
        }
        cout << input_values[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int* userInput(int input_values[], int size)
{
   int user_input[50];
   for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
       cout << "Provide input: ";
       cin >> user_input[50];
    }
    return user_input;
}
```

The program keeps crashing with error code 255 unless I stop it early (in which it returns some weird negative value).

The program is a solution for a Practice Problem in Jumping into C++, on sorting arrays (namely, it's the Insertion Sort).

This is the problem itself:

> Write a program that takes in 50 values and prints out the highest,
>   the lowest, the average and then all 50 input values, one per line.

I've edited this post with the latest update to the code.  I just keep getting this weird array output even after including the return statement

```
return user_input;
```

So what's with this?   It just gives me the warning:

> warning: address of local variable 'user_input' returned [enabled by
>   default]

concerning the return statement.

Comment: "Crashing with error code 255" is pretty vague. What kind of crash is it?

Answer (score 1):

You do this:

> userInput(input_values[50], 50)

which should be

> userInput(input_values, 50)

you do this multiple times.
Second remark: you can also take input in a loop, in the same way as you do cout in the main part of your program.

Comment: I'm getting a weird output, still.  Could you run the fixed version I made I try running it?  I could email it to you if you tell me your email address.